# "Create Launcher..." on desktop did not work

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

"Create Folder" and "Create Document" worked well. But nothing happened when click "Create Launcher". It's annoying to create launchers in Terminal. so what can I do?

Comment: For what application you want to create a launcher? And how did you create a launcher?

Comment: I copy and edit *.desktop files from /usr/share/applications.

Answer (score 4):

What happens when you issue the following command from a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)?:

`gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new $HOME/Desktop`

Comment: command not found :(

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 11.04. And Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity on my part, let's something a little different.  I am going to assume that you do not have 'Ubuntu-Tweak' installed.  If you do, skip this step.  From a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) issue the following command:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

Once 'Ubuntu-Teak' is installed (or if it is already installed), start it.  Under the Desktop section, select Desktop Icon Settings.  Does your setup look like what it pictured below?

[image]

I was thinking that if the 'Show desktop icons' option was not enabled that you would not be able to create a new launcher on the desktop.  Please let me know what you find.